# How do I get DotNet Core 3.0 to recognize certain statements from DotNet Framework?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-core-3.0

I'm new to dotnet core and I'm trying to upgrade a project from VB.Net 2010 using dotnet framework 4.x to VB.Net 2019 using dotnet core 3.0.  Currently I'm just upgrading some user controls and the first two went fine, but the third one gives me an error with the statement

MyBase.Text = FormatNumber(MyBase.Text, Decimals, TriState.True, TriState.False, ShowComma)

It doesn't like the FormatNumber statement.

In my old project I had some references to System, system.Core, system.Data, System.Drawing, system.windowsm.forms, System.XML,and system.XML.Linq via DLL's from the program files directory.  Are there dll's I should be referencing for dotnet core 3.0 to get reference to all of the namespaces.

I have imported these namespaces, but I don't know how to reference them or even if I need to.

Perhaps FormatNumber needs to be referenced by it's full namespace name, but I don't even know what that is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: FormatNumber is in the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.  Check if .NET Core have an equivalent for this.

Comment: If you try "Strings.FormatNumber" instead, does it work?

Comment: Actually, try: Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FormatNumber

Comment: For the others, first try to find a NuGet package.

Comment: I love "upgrate a project" It describes many kinds of updates or upgrades I have been through. :-)

Comment: You should never have been using `FormatNumber` in the first place.  Call `ToString` on a number to convert it to a `String` with or without formatting or call `String.Format` for composite formatting. That works in every version of .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Yes, but the VB methods should be available by now - see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-in-net-core-3-0/

Comment: My question has to do with should I have to add any references to make this work or should it work because VB methods are supposed to be available?  I have found others that don't work as well and I haven't even got to the hard part.  Isn't dotnet core supposed to have all the same capabilities as dotnet framework?

Comment: For Dave Doknjas, Strings.FormatNumber and Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FormatNumber were tried before I posted this question and they don't work.  But thanks for the guidance.